# Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-23'

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

Hi I'm having a problem whit my android studio configuration, when I tried to sync graddle I keep recieving the following error:

Comment: May be you did n't installed android-23 version sdk, install that tools and try...Post full error

Comment: Hi thats the full error i got.

Comment: I just add all the errors I found, its seems like it´s a certificate issue or something like that

Comment: if possible share screenshot when it is coming,I did't understand, post the gradle file also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was an error with the proxy, i was using the notebook from my company and it has a proxy configurated, so I add the proxy on http proxy setting and its working now